# How can I use an InheritedWidget to initialize the attributes of a State object?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to write a game using Flutter. I have a list of words loaded from a file which make up a master dictionary. Each time the user plays the game, a random word is selected from the master dictionary which is then used to initialize some parameters for that specific instance of the game.

I would like to store the dictionary in an Application object that gets accessed by one or more Game objects. I'm trying to do this by creating an InheritedWidget that contains a Dictionary object representing the master word list.

The problem I'm having is that the game's State object seems unable to access the data contained within the InheritedWidget. I read that `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` isn't useable from `initState` and to get the data in `didChangeDependencies` but neither seems to work for me.

This is how I wrote my `InheritedWidget` to encapsulate a `Dictionary` object.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import "dart:math";


// Used to read and store a list of words from a file
class Dictionary {
  static final Random _rnd = Random();
  final List<String> wordList;

  Dictionary(this.wordList);

  static Future<Dictionary> loadFromFile(String path) async {
    String textContents = await rootBundle.loadString(path);
    List<String> wordList = textContents.split('\r\n');
    return Dictionary(wordList);
  }

  String getRandomWord() {
    int randomIndex = _rnd.nextInt(wordList.length);
    return wordList[randomIndex];
  }
}

// InheritedWidget intended to provide a dictionary object representing
// a master word list to widgets further down the tree.
class DictionaryWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  final Dictionary dictionary;

  const DictionaryWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.dictionary,
    required super.child,
  });

  static DictionaryWidget? maybeOf(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<DictionaryWidget>();
  }

  static DictionaryWidget of(BuildContext context) {
    final DictionaryWidget? result = maybeOf(context);
    assert(result != null, 'No DictionaryWidget found in context');
    return result!;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(DictionaryWidget oldWidget) => dictionary != oldWidget.dictionary;
}
```

Here is my main application code. For the purposes of a minimal example I've taken out a bunch of stuff. `ApplicationState` uses a `FutureBuilder` to display a progress indicator until the dictionary is loaded. After that it displays a button allowing the user to start a new game which creates a new `Game` object and displays it.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: Application())
      )
    )
  );
}


class Application extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String dictPath = 'assets/dictionary.txt';
  static final masterWordList = Dictionary.loadFromFile(dictPath);

  const Application({super.key});

  @override
  State<Application> createState() => ApplicationState();
}

class ApplicationState extends State<Application> {
  Game? currentGame;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Wait to load the master word list from the file. Once loaded,
    // create a new Game object and display it.
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Application.masterWordList,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // if word list has finished loading
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
              && !snapshot.hasError
              && snapshot.hasData) {
            return (currentGame != null)
                  // if a new game has been created, display it
                  // encapsulated in a DictionaryWidget so that the master
                  // dictionary can be accessed by games
                  ? DictionaryWidget(
                      dictionary: snapshot.data!,
                      child: currentGame!
                  )
                  // if no current game display a button to create one
                  : TextButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () {
                        currentGame = const Game();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => currentGame)
                        );
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                      label: const Text("New Game"),
            );
          }
          // error handling
          else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          }
          // if word list not loaded, display a progress indicator while loading
          else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Everything up to this point works as expected. I now try to create a `Game` object, but no matter what I try, when I try to traverse back up the widget tree, it fails to find a DictionaryWidget. I've blockquoted what I've tried below.

- Attempts 1a, 1c, and 2 fail the assertion in `DictionaryWidget.of`.
- Attempt 1b won't execute and says `BuildContext.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType` does not exist.

Game code:

```
// widget representing a game being played
class Game extends StatefulWidget {
  const Game({super.key});

  @override
  State<Game> createState() => GameState();
}

// game needs to pick a word at random from the master word list
class GameState extends State<Game> {
  late final String randomWord;

  /*--------------------ATTEMPT #1------------------
  //tried using initState
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // access the master word list
    // none of these worked

    //---------------------ATTEMPT 1a-------------------
    //Dictionary masterWordList = DictionaryWidget.of(context).dictionary;

    /*---------------------ATTEMPT 1b-------------------
    Dictionary masterWordList = context
      .ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(DictionaryWidget)
      ?.widget
      .dictionary;
    */
    /*---------------------ATTEMPT 1c-------------------
    Dictionary? masterWordList = context
      .findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<DictionaryWidget>()
      ?.dictionary;
    assert(masterWordList != null, "Received null ancestor.");
    */

    randomWord = masterWordList!.getRandomWord();
  }
  */

  /*---------------------ATTEMPT 2-------------------
  //using didChangeDependencies
  bool isInitialized = false;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if (!isInitialized) {
      Dictionary masterWordList = DictionaryWidget.of(context).dictionary;

      // get a random word
      randomWord = masterWordList.getRandomWord();
      isInitialized = true;
    }
  }
  */

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // normally a bunch of widgets involving the gameplay would be displayed here
    return Text("The random word is $randomWord");
  }
}
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious but I'm really at a loss. It doesn't seem like it should be this difficult to pass data down the tree.

**EDIT**
I realized that in the new game button's `onPressed` function I was creating a new `currentGame` variable that was local only to that function, instead of updating the instance attribute. I've fixed that but the issue still remains.

Comment: I think the new route has a different context tree, so it won't see the DictionaryWidget on this context tree at all.

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense. I tried having the `MaterialPageRoute` builder return a `DictionaryWidget` encapsulating the new `Game` instead of the `Game` itself and that seems to work. But since `builder` takes a context as a parameter I'm assuming I should have been able to forward that to the new `Game` instead which seems more elegant to me. How can I provide the existing context tree to `Game` in `MaterialPageRoute.builder`?

Comment: builder *provides* a *new* context to the build function.